# Add a method to a custom control that I can access from the client with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET custom control that extends the DropDownList. Now I want to add a method that I can call with javascript from the client that clears any user selection and resets the list to the default. So far I have been unable to get it right. The code below returns and exception, **0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'clearSelection'**.

In the ASP.NET control I have:

```
public void clearSelection()
{
    //... code to reset the list
}
```

and in the aspx page I have some javascript that attempts to invoke the method.

```
var control = $("body").find('<%=uxBillTo.ClientID %>');
if (control != null) {
    control.clearSelection();
}
```

Comment: Don't believe C# methods are exposed as JS methods to the client.

Comment: Take a look at the following which describes calling "Page Methods" in your code behind in ASP.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437344/call-method-in-code-behind-secure-page-from-client-javascipt

Comment: While you're at it: replace `<%=ux...` with `<%:ux...` so you get automatic encoding.

Comment: Just do it in JS with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985072/how-do-i-clear-the-dropdownlist-values-on-button-cick-event-using-jquery